# How to encrypt Spring OAuth Token?

Tags: spring, encryption, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to implement Spring OAuth2 in my Spring REST application. What I have already achieved:

1. Generate a token while logging in.
2. Store this token on the client side, use it for every request I do from UI.

What I want to achieve:
1. Encrypt the token stored on the client side & send this encrypted token instead of sending the actual token.

Are there any services available in the Spring OAuth2 project to achieve this?
Any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I know oauth2 servers and clients usually run in SSH channels, if you use SSH there is no need to encrypt theme.

Secondly access_token is stored in a cookie on client side. if you want to encrypt it you must consider which your oauth2 server should be able to decrypt it too!

Thirdly your scenario is already have been implemented by JWT!
take a look at :
https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2

Comment: OP's question was to Encrypt the token, not encode it.